# Mongoose Query for Null Population

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

I've got these two models, Product and Design. Product has a design field that takes a Design ObjectId.

Sometimes, though, when saving to mlab db, a Design doesn't finish saving, but still returns an ObjectId to save to Product, so for some products when I query

```
Product.find({...});
```

I get back Product.design = someObjectId;

But when I populate:

```
Product.find({...}).populate('design');
```

the resulting product.design is null, which makes sense. Now I need to patch it back up. I've been doing a query of all Products, populating 'design', then iterating through each product to see if its product design === null, but with over 50K Product docs in the db, I'd prefer to write a more specific query, so:

What query do I need to run to return only Products with design fields that populate to null?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to do something like this?

```
Product.find(design : { exists : false }).exec(function(err,doc){
  if (err) throw err;
  //this will be docs with design set to null
  console.log(doc)
})
```

Updated:  Let me know if that is what you need.

Comment: Nope! the design field is already filled in with an ObjectId, it just doesn't link to an existing doc. Running Product.find({design:""}) returns []

Comment: Still not. Think of it this way: the affected Product, when I just run Product.find({...}) looks like this: {_id: 56902c2263b132b0976c14ad, created: 2016-03-23T23:07:19.759Z, design: 5660effabb790c22059a4114}

But when I run Product.find({...}).populate('design'), I get back: {_id: 56902c2263b132b0976c14ad, created: 2016-03-23T23:07:19.759Z, design: null}

Because there is no Design with that ObjectId. But in the initial query, the product still has a design field. So checking for {$exists: false, $ne: ""} doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any reason why you couldn't try to populate all documents, then run a second query to see which documents have a design field of null, and then make your updates from there?  I can't think of a better way of handling, but someone else may have a better solution.

Comment: Like I commented above, that's what I've been doing, I was just hoping there was a better way since I have over 50K products in the database & it's unknown whether or not the underlying problem is resolved

Comment: I have encountered the same problem. Did you find any solutions regarding this? @Robin